# phpexcel selecting non-adjacent cells

Tags: php, phpexcel

Does anyone know how to reference non-adjacent cells in PHPExcel?

eg:

`$sheet->getStyle('B2,C8')->applyFromArray()`

Do I have to split them in two seperate lines or is there a way to combine them? I've done more research on this than I thought I should have to, can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may select only single cells or range of cells so if You need to select multiple cells that are not next to each other You have to make it in 2 steps.

Comment: If it is just few cells it is not a big problem. If it is bigger number maybe there is some patter and You could use loop to do it.

Comment: It's a part of the roadmap for this year, to rationalise the way we handle cell references in calls so that PHPExcel will be consistent in its use of comma separated lists, ranges and individual cell references between different methods; but getStyle() currently only has options for an individual cell reference or for a range of cells

Answer (score 3):

You **have to** make two calls, in your case:

```
$sheet->getStyle('B2')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
$sheet->getStyle('C8')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
```

Besides, I think you have to pass at least one parameter, an array with style definitions